# Equal Levels in Pandas Group By Object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to make levels in each group equal even if the values in the levels are not equal between the groups. Below is the example of what I want to achieve:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo']*3 + ['bar']*4,
   ...:                    'B' : [0,1,2,0,1,2,3],
   ...:                    'C' : np.random.randn(7)})
```

Now, if I group by columns `A` and `B`, the output will be as follows:

```
>> print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum())
A   B          
bar 0 -1.452272
    1  0.331986
    2  0.764295
    3  1.863472
foo 0 -1.066971
    1 -0.411573
    2  0.158449
```

I want to achieve as follows:

```
A   B          
bar 0 -1.452272
    1  0.331986
    2  0.764295
    3  1.863472
foo 0 -1.066971
    1 -0.411573
    2  0.158449
    3  0.000000
```

I searched a lot about this, but not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `unstack` and `stack` after your code

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
Out[372]: 
              C
A   B          
bar 0 -0.243351
    1 -0.568541
    2  1.529810
    3 -0.327521
foo 0 -2.380512
    1  1.088617
    2 -0.125879
    3  0.000000
```

Comment: This is awesome. I wanted an answer as succinct as yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `pd.crosstab` and `stack`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['A'], df['B'], df['C'], aggfunc='sum').stack(dropna=False).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
A    B
bar  0    0.553563
     1    0.357182
     2   -0.294756
     3    1.176766
foo  0   -0.514786
     1    1.841072
     2    0.792337
     3    0.000000
dtype: float64
```